# en next 13 como puedo agregar el metadato de openGraph "amount" de forma dinamica

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, next.js, meta-tags

quiero que se genere el metadato amount ya que meta requiere esa información de el producto pero no se como generarla en next 13 de forma dinamica :

```
<meta property="product:price:amount" content="7.99">
```

alguna idea de como pudiera resolver este problema ?

```
export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {
      const response = await ...


  return {

    openGraph: {
      product:{
        price:{
          amount:150000
        }
      },
      title: response.data.programName,
      description: response.data.description,
      url: '...',
      siteName: '...',
      locale: 'es_ES',
      type: 'website',
    },

  };


  

}
export default...
```